# Batch - Echo or Variable Not Working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this little batch script:

```
SET @var = "GREG"
ECHO %@var%
PAUSE
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
H:\Dynamics>SET @var = "GREG"

H:\Dynamics>ECHO
ECHO is on.

H:\Dynamics>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why won't it print the contents of @var?  How do I know if @var is even being set?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Dont use spaces:

```
SET @var="GREG"
::instead of SET @var = "GREG"
ECHO %@var%
PAUSE
```

Comment: %@var% doesn't work it's %var% (at least on Windows 10)

Comment: @nasch, why sould `%@var%` not work? `@` can occur in variable names just like letters, also on Windows 10. (The `@` has got special meaning only when being at the beginning of a command line and defines to not echo it out…)

Comment: @aschipfl I do not remember what the issue was from 2019.  Presumably I tried it one way and it worked, and the other way didn't.

Answer (score 31):

Try the following (note that there should not be a space between the `VAR`, `=`, and `GREG`).

```
SET VAR=GREG
ECHO %VAR%
PAUSE
```

Comment: that reminds me of a story. A man had been hired to paint a sign for a fish and chip shop. The owner was unhappy with the result and he said "there needs to be more space between fish and and and and and chips".

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @youcantexplainthat The answer is here - [What are some examples of awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences/2672#2672)

Comment: There needs to be more space between "Fish" and "and" and [also between] "and" and "chips".

Answer (score -1):

Im new to this but maybe trying  semicolon at the end of declaring the variable?

```
SET @var="GREG":
ECHO %@var%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Cmd doesn't use any "end of command" token. (by the way: you said "semicolon", but used a colon - probably a typo). The true issue is the spaces around the `=` (as already answered 13 years ago)